# Is it harder to get visa for longer duration as compared to short duration?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

Wanted to know if shorter duration schengen visa are easier to get like 10 or 15 days while longer duration like 30+ days are harder to get? is there a relation or not?

Comment: I don’t have any hard data for this, but I would think it shouldn’t be much different _per se_, but of course, depending on your circumstances like purpose of travel, who pays, your financial situation, etc, it _may_ become harder to justify why you are going to stay that long, how you are going to pay for it, how you can get away from your source of income for that long, and so on. But again, it will depend a lot on your circumstances.

Comment: I'll disagree with @jcaron's conclusion here. A longer-duration visa will by definition afford the grantee greater privileges than a shorter-duration one: some combination of longer time in the Schengen area and/or more than one entry. Thus, I think the issuing country will therefore set the bar higher, for exactly the reasons listed in the comment.

Comment: If they decide to give you permission to enter, the length of stay is pretty irrelevant IMHO. Once you’re in, you’re in.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica given the timescales given by OP I was thinking about the shorter types of visas (a few weeks) with one or two entries. Longer visas (valid for one or more years, with multiple entries) are indeed harder to get, and in theory one can in most cases only get them after several successful short stays.

Comment: @Traveller for someone whose ability to afford the trip is in doubt, the fact that a longer trip costs more than a shorter one would certainly be significant.

Comment: @phoog Of course, however the OP hasn’t given any indication that’s their reason for asking this question. Voted to close.